# Windows 8 Style Start Screen Tiles for Website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, windows-8

I'm working on a project that gives people a new browser homepage to be displayed when they open their browser window or new tab. This page will have icons/tiles to popular websites and at some point their own customised websites.

What I want to do is to have tiles that look like that of Windows 8 and have the flip and zoom to full screen effect that they do in the real Windows 8 start screen upon clicking on it, where it will show the icon and site title while the page loads.

I'm not looking to load the site into the homepage, as it will direct them to the site being clicked on, but until they get to the site, it will show the icon and site title on the screen.

Any suggestions as to how this can be achieved along with some examples would be awesome.

Thank you in advance for your time, and I look forward to your response.

Comment: This sounds like an interesting project - please show us what you have tried so far, and what errors/problems if any you have encountered. It might also be helpful to give a brief overview of what you have researched so far.

Answer (score 0):

There's a pseudo-class if you want to have fullscreen specific styles.
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen

I think most of your problems will be: selecting a **grid** system or thechnique to layout those tiles. The zoom and flip effects should be done with the `transform` property.

Checkout what I've found: http://metroui.org.ua/tiles.html (A style guide with **win8** components)

Here's another example by the amazing Sara Soueidan: sarasoueidan . com/demos/windows8-animations  (*couldn't paste the link because of my low reputation points*)

If you need JS or you want to just go with cross-browsers compatibilities, check out this lib. It's just great: **GSAP**

**Pro Tip**: this is going to be your friend: `backface-visibility: hidden;`